# Rationals $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ are isomorphic to a part of a finite partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, rational-numbers

I believe the following statement is true but I can't find or figure out a proof:

*For any partition of the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals into a finite number of parts, there is a part containing an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ (preserving the < relation)*

This is hinted at in passing in a paper by Hasson, Kojman and Onshuus (www.math.bgu.ac.il/~kojman/symindiv.pdf) who call this property 'indivisibility'.

I think IF I can prove (and it is true) that any finite partition of $\mathbb{Q}$ must include a part containing an interval $\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b)$ then I can use the function $f(x)=a + \frac{1+x/(1+|x|)}{2(b-a)}$.

1. Is this function an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}→\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ preserving $<$ ?
2. Is it true that in a partition of finitely many parts, one must contain an interval $\mathbb{Q}
   \cap(a,b)$?
3. Is there any other way of proving the statement?

This feels like it should be easy and I'm just missing something, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Use the result that every countable dense linear order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$; the proof is a standard example of a [back and forth argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Comment: Your assumption is not true: partition $\mathbb Q$ into numbers having odd vs. even denominators.

Comment: Also, is there a commonly used term used for this property of a structure S ("For any partition of S into a finite number of parts, there is a part containing an isomorphic copy of S")? This would help in searching for other structures with this property

Comment: Thanks very much @Brian. I can't figure out how to use the back-and-forth method. I have seen it used in graph theory where you consider the points already mapped connected and not connected to the next vertex. What would be the parallel here? Also how would you define the mapping of the 'first' point when \mathbb{Q} stretches from -inf to -inf?

Comment: @Saj: It’s actually carried out in detail in [one of the sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets) of the Wikipedia article to which I linked.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove the result for a partition into two parts, $A$ and $B$, say.
Also, it suffices to show that one of $A,B$ contains a countable dense subset without endpoints (cf. ''Brian M. Scott's'' comment). Of course, the endpoint condition is harmless as we can simply remove them (we want to show only that one of the parts *contains* an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb Q$).

If one parts avoids an interval, say $A\cap (a,b)=\emptyset$, then $(a,b)\cap\mathbb Q\subseteq B$ and we are done. This includes the case that one of the sets is bounded from above or below or even finite.
Hence $A$ (as well as $B$) can be assumed as infinite. It is also dense, for if $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$ then as just seen $(a,b)\cap A$ is not empty.

Comment: Thanks very much. So just to clarify, in the case A∩(a,b)=∅ can I use the function f(x)=a+1+x/(1+|x|)2(b−a) to explicitly define an isomorphism?